# I tried to handle an Axios error. It doesn't work, how to handle it correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, discord.js

I'm making a Discord bot, now I'm working at commands that interact with Geometry Dash API. I'm using **axios** to fetch the level info, and when I type the existing ID, I get the correct and working result. But if I'll type the incorrect ID, I get a **-1** error. I tried to handle this error, but nothing works. What should I do?

```
const axios = require("axios");
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  const id = args[0];
  axios.get(`https://gdbrowser.com/api/level/${id}`).then((response) => {
    try {
    const { data } = response;
    const { name, id, description, author, difficulty, downloads, length, stars, orbs, diamonds, featured, epic, gameVersion, version, coins, verifiedCoins, starsRequested, ldm, objects } = data;
    message.channel.send(`Name: ${name}\nID: ${id}\nDesc: ${description}\nAuthor: ${author}\nDifficulty: ${difficulty}\nDownloads: ${downloads}\nLength: ${length}\nStars: ${stars}\nOrbs: ${orbs}\nDiamonds: ${diamonds}\nFeatured: ${featured}\nEpic: ${epic}\nGame Ver: ${gameVersion}\nVersion: ${version}\nCoins: ${coins}\nVerified Coins: ${verifiedCoins}\nStarsReq: ${starsRequested}\nLDM: ${ldm}\nObjects: ${objects}`)
    } catch (e) {
      if(data === -1) {
      return;
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Have you read https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors?

Comment: `I get a -1 error` where should you get this "error" - you check `if(data === -1)` inside the catch, but `data` equalling -1 won't throw an error - in fact, the `catch` block won't even have access to the `data` variable from the `try` block - you should check for that condition inside the `try` block - (in fact you don't even NEED a try/catch to check `if (data === -1)`)

Comment: I have earlier read this documentation, but I didn't understand why it's not handling. Tried to read again, that worked and helped.

Comment: @Mipper6 Please post your update as an answer to your own question instead of putting it as an update to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already fixed it. **-1** was the `error.response.data`.